# How to find the block number of a transaction in a Wolfram Blockchain?

Tags: data, dataset, finance, data-acquisition, cryptography

For example, in block 1004 of the Wolfram Blockchain, I can get the 4th transaction's ID by using the following code:-

```
tranID = BlockchainBlockData[1004]["TransactionList"][[4]]
```

Then I have `f82c26a69b207f260f3a410d2931c8b749cb22a11b052b91ea79748835bd`. It is an interesting image of a cube. You can try to see the image by typing:-

```
BlockchainGet[tranID]
```

My question is, if the situation is reversed, i.e. I have `f82c26a69b207f260f3a410d2931c8b749cb22a11b052b91ea79748835bd` but I don't have the block number `1004`, how can I obtain the block number `1004`? I tried below, but there's no luck.

```
tranData = BlockchainTransactionData[tranID];
tranData // Dataset
tranData["Inputs"] // Dataset
tranData["Outputs"] // Dataset
```

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, BlockchainTransactionData doesn't return that information about the Wolfram blockchain. Note that blockchain functionalities are marked as experimental and that means they can change between releases. Blockchain functions introduced in v12 are more focused on Bitcoin and Ethereum. You can see some examples here:

https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/blockchain/?product=mathematica